# Messages on Mac. How to keep audio messages from expiring?

Tags: macos, messages

On iOS, under Settings > Messages there is a section called Audio Messages and you can select the length of time before expiry. I have always had it as "Never".

On Mac however, it seems that I have to manually click "keep" to prevent Messages from erasing audio messages?

Am I missing something?

I am on 10.12.1

Comment: No, there is no option to disable expiration.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Just to be specific, clicking "Keep" DOES disable expiration.  The OP is asking if there is a setting to enable it globally.